# Another term for "controlled like a puppet"?

Tags: synonyms, speech

What's another word or phrase for "**being controlled like a puppet**".

eg., *"to be manipulated by a more powerful force"* . . . what the puppet is *enduring*?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you're asking for, preferably by adding an example sentence with some underscores to represent the missing word. As it currently stands, it's unclear whether you want an adjective such as *manipulated* ("controlled like a puppet") or a noun such as *manipulation* ("*being* controlled like a puppet" or "what the puppet is enduring"). An example sentence provides the context for us to be able to provide an answer. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Comment: Do you mean something like **enslaved**? You have to be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

You can say:

''***keep on a string''***

According to [Collin's Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep-on-a-string) :

***keep on a string***

to have control or a hold over (someone), esp emotionally.

One more dictionary entry:

[On a string](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+someone+on+a+string)

: Under someone's control, influence, or manipulation.

"She kept teasing him with the possibility of a relationship in order to ***keep*** him ***on a*** ***string***, convincing him buy her clothes and pay for her rent."